# Composer.phar in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I am trying to install the fosuserbundle in my composer.json but this problem appears in my console:

```
C:\xamppHE\php>php composer.phar install

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): Crea
teProcess failed, error code - 0' in phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/
symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 1013

ErrorException: proc_open(): CreateProcess failed, error code - 0 in phar://C:/x
amppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Applic
ation.php on line 1013

Call Stack:
0.0140     235464   1. {main}() C:\xamppHE\php\composer.phar:0
0.0150     234136   2. require('phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/bin/comp
oser') C:\xamppHE\php\composer.phar:15
0.4280    2045032   3. Composer\Console\Application->run() phar://C:/xamppHE
/php/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
0.4570    2262672   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() phar://C
:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
0.8780    2717120   5. Composer\Console\Application->renderException() phar:
//C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/
Application.php:128
1.1730    2732960   6. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->renderExceptio
n() phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:163

1.1730    2733808   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWid
th() phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Componen
t/Console/Application.php:731
1.1730    2733824   8. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDim
ensions() phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Com
ponent/Console/Application.php:797
1.1740    2734024   9. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getConsoleMode
() phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/
Console/Application.php:827
1.1740    2735320  10. proc_open() phar://C:/xamppHE/php/composer.phar/vendo
r/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:1013
1.1780    2736152  11. Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() phar://C:/xamppH
E/php/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application
```

.php:1013

My Symfony version is 2.3.5, with PHP 5.4.19 and my OS is Windows Vista. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like problem caused by insufficient privileges.

Since you're using Vista, have you tried running command prompt as an Elevated user (right-click, "Run as Administrator")?